# Wordpress reload post/page if ! is_user_logged_in (and #anchor not in URL)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, anchor

Have a CPT that I want to put a test on when it loads. (So, working in single-cpt.php.)

Basically want to load (or reload?) the page with an #anchor in it, which will display a call to action overlay, **IF** a user is NOT logged in. So this:

```
if (! is_user_logged_in() ) {
   header('Location: #anchor');
}
```

But also want to check if already has anchor in place `page#anchor` in URL. Either from a direct link or from the above is_user_logged_in forcing it on there. (This would also prevent the above code from infinitely trying to reload that page, as user still hasn't logged in.)

I've found a few things, but also I have come across notes (most a few years old so don't know if still is current state) that PHP isn't very good at being able to detect #anchors present on client side. Did try a few things like the following.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'#anchor') == true) {
}
```

So what is the best way to run the two tests? Especially if one has to be done in PHP and the other in... javascript?? Does it matter which order to test, as at that really matters both conditions being true (user not logged in and page not yet showing anchor) would cause the page to reload with #anchor in URL. Otherwise, the anchor is already causing the overlay to appear, or the user is logged in and just sees a normal page.

Comment: Have you considered using a query string parameter instead?

Comment: I second the query string suggestions. This is not what the url fragment (#) should be used for. Hashes (#) in the url are designed to identify a specific location in the document, not pass information to the server. That is what query parameters are for.

Comment: Thank you both. No I hadn't considered using a query string because A) just looking at this (but now I've learned that PHP isn't good for looking at the URL) and B) I was working with things built into the theme.   But, your comments and fresh eyes today, made me look through the source code of the theme. Found where they overlay is called. Now instead of testing for the anchor (which would have told me the overlay is active), I'm just going to call the overlay directly. Single step and much cleaner that way.